# Finding the multivariate distribution of a stochastic matrix

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

I'm currently writing my thesis and derived some closed form solutions. However, these solutions need to get estimated to use in practice. I thus should know the multivariate distributions of some stochasts. The found formula is as follows:

$\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i} var(\bar{c}_{i,j}) - cov( c_{i,j} , \bar{c}_{i,j} )}{ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j\neq i} var( c_{i,j} - \bar{c}_{i,j} ) }$

Where $c_{i,j}$ refers to the (i,j) th element of a sample correlation matrix and $\bar{c}_{i,j}$ refers to the (i,j) th element of a matrix where each offdiagonal element have been replaced by the average of the offdiagonal elements $c_{i,j}$.

The matrices $C$ (with elements $c_{i,j}$) and $\bar{C}$ (with elements $\bar{c}_{i,j}$) can be considered as stochasts as they change over time. I should find distributiions for $C$ and $\bar{C}$, but I just don't really know how to tackle this problem.

I think I should bring the central limit theorem in somewhere to approximate the limiting distributions of $C$ and $\bar{C}$ ..? I would highly appreciate some help as I am not that genious with statistics..

Thanks in advance!